# Linearly dependent features with categorical variables

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-encoding, dependent-variable

My dataset contains 350 indicator variables, which are grouped by category (i.e. they are the result of applying one-hot-encoding to categorical variables). For example, the first three indicator variables specify the location of a property (`i1`=north, `i2`=center, `i3`=south), the next three indicator variables specify the color of walls (`j1`=blue, `j2`=red, `j3`=other), ...

Let's say I want to predict the property price (`y`) using ordinary least squares regression.

To avoid the [dummy variable trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588876/dummy-variable-trap-in-ols-with-multiple-indicator-variables), I drop the last column for each group of categorical variables.

Can I still face the problem that some features are linearly dependent on others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good thing to drop one category for each of your variables, as explained in the link you mention. But otherwise, it's still possible to have multicollinearity in your model, for example if the "location of a property" variable is somehow related to the "color of walls" variable. Multicollinearity may or may not be a problem, for example depending on what you want to do exactly with your model. Maybe not an issue if your problem is prediction and nothing else, but more details would probably be helpful if this is not a theoretical question.